# What does Cocoa Touch's canonical NSUnicodeStringEncoding mean?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, encoding

Is it UTF-16? 32? Something else?

I want to look into this for performance reasons, since I'm converting a lot of strings from UTF-8 to "native `NSString`", and the performance penalty seems to land on `__CFFromUTF8`, which is a built-in conversion function. Btw: I'm just guessing that`NSUnicodeStringEncoding` is what is used internally, since `NSString`'s `fastestEncoding` returns that value (i.e. for international strings; when using ANSI, MacRomans is returned).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing using `dataUsingEncoding:` indicates `NSUnicodeStringEncoding` is little-endian UTF-16 preceded with a byte order mark (on both the simulator and a real device) and Apple's [String Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/stringsClusters.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008025-SW1) says "NSString objects are conceptually UTF-16 with platform endianness", so I'd think it's reasonable to assume UTF-16 is used internally.

(the same guide goes on to say "That doesn’t necessarily imply anything about their internal storage mechanism", so they're fully reserving the right to change this in future)