# Objective-C differences in UTF-8 & UTF-16 strings as bytes

Tags: c, cocoa, encoding, nsstring

I am trying to convert NSStrings to byte arrays and then back to NSStrings.  I have tried with NSUnicodeEncoding and NSUTF8StringEncoding.  My question is that as I iterate over the byte arrays, I'm seeing different data

Only change in this code is that I change NSUTF8StringEncoding to NSUnicodeEncoding and that I add dataLength += 2 so that it accounts for the BOM.

```
NSString *message = @"testing";
NSUInteger dataLength = [message lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
void *byteData = malloc( dataLength );
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [message length]);
BOOL result =   [message getBytes:byteData maxLength:dataLength usedLength:&actualLength encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding options:0  range:range remainingRange:&remain];
for( NSUInteger x = 0; x < dataLength; x++ )
{
    NSLog( @"byte data: %s", (char *)byteData);
    int t = (int)*(char *)byteData;
    byteData++;
}
```

The difference is in the NSLog :
As NSUTF8StringEncoding I see

- testing`
- esting`
- sting`
- ting`
- ...

As NSUnicodeEncoding I see

- null
- t
- null
- e
- ...

The int t value is correct for the given character, but I don't understand why the byteData is so different.  I would expect them both to act like the NSUnicodeEncoding.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between UTF-8 and UTF-16 as representations? I'm not sure why you'd expect them to be similar...

Comment: I'm just learning, but I do understand some of the differences.  My question was more related to why is the data being logged so different.  I assumed I was logging a byte at a time and didn't understand how multiple characters could be one byte.

Comment: It's the reverse - you *are* logging one byte at a time, but each UTF-16 code unit is 2 bytes.

Comment: I'm not sure if I was clear in what I meant - I didn't understand how a call to Log( @"byte data: %s", (char *)byteData); which I thought would log one byte at a time was logging testing' for one call.  But from reading David's answer - it seems that the format specifier I was using was incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UTF8, the letter F is represented by a single F byte. The string "FU" is represented by an ASCII F byte followed by an ASCII U byte. In Unicode (as used here), each character occupies two bytes. Standard ASCII characters are preceded by a zero byte.

It's not clear why the behavior you see isn't exactly what you'd expect. In UTF-8, standard ASCII characters occupy one byte. In your Unicode encoding, the occupy two. So it certainly won't be at all the same.

Comment: I was expecting that when I was logging the current byte in the byte array for it to be one byte.  The data logged ( testing', esting', ... ) seemed that at each log statement writing more than one byte.  Is that wrong?

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have done it.  I understand the basic idea of a pointer, but I still get lost in some of the notation and usage.  Its interesting that I used the correct notation when casting to an int but the wrong when logging.  I think that is because that logging was working correctly for the UTF-16 data - which as you said has nul bytes every other position.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841295/what-does-cocoa-touchs-canonical-nsunicodestringencoding-mean/4842249#4842249), `NSUnicodeStringEncoding` "is little-endian UTF-16 preceded with a byte order mark", so it should be expected that the result is totally different than UTF-8.